# Xcode: ABBYY:Load the license file to the memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to use the ABBYY iOS trial after given the trial key, according to the document I am supposed to load the license into memory, and the guide given was:

> ABBYY Mobile OCR Engine license is stored in a license file (*.License).
>
> To add license information to an application, do the following:
>
> - Load the license file to the memory
> - Assign the LicenseData field of the FINE_LICENSE_INFO structure to a pointer to the memory buffer, which contains loaded data
> - Specify the DataLength and ApplicationID fields of the structure. The ApplicationID field must correspond to an application name in the license file.
> - Pass a constant pointer to the FINE_LICENSE_INFO variable to the FineSetLicenseInfo function.
>
> Use the FineGetLicenseInfo function to get information about the current license.

But I am really new to Xcode, so how do I actually load the license file into the memory? Can someone give me a detailed guide?